# 4-way foldable X joint

Tags: joinery, joints, box-joint

I'm trying to design a 4-way X-shaped foldable joint. Something that is 4-legged and connects at the middle, but can also be folded up into a straight object. Is this possible? What would be the name of such a joint?

I've found this image online that seems to be close to the type of joint that I'm looking for:

[image]

I also created this simple X structure with some pencils so that you could get a better idea of what I'm referring to (although the joint I'm looking for wouldn't be connected with rubber bands, but instead pins maybe?):

[image]

Basically I want to make this: but with 4 legs instead of 3:

[image]

I'm hoping to find some sort of design that I can copy and create a 3D rendering of.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Taking some inspiration from this on DIY https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/92471/how-to-construct-this-4-way-x-table-leg-arrangement I think this should be doable if you're willing to compromise a bit on the exact form of the joint, using some simple hinging (using either actual hinges or leather/cloth strap hinges). But, is the actual need here just something that can be broken down, rather than it *having* to be a four-way X-brace type thing? Because there are numerous existing knockdown (k/d) furniture design one could copy instead.

Comment: Hello  thank you!  
Yes it would need to be "broken down" or folded up 

Comment: In the question Graphus linked, the two cross braces are made with half-lap joints. The two braces could, themselves, then be half-lapped to fit together vertically. Without any fasteners, you would then be able to slip the legs back apart and flat-pack them next to the top.